# Custom Form Validation in Django-Allauth

Tags: django-allauth

I want to do some extra validation on fields in django-allauth.  For example I want to prevent using free email addresses. So I want to run this method on signup

```
def clean_email(self):
    email_domain = self.cleaned_data['email'].split('@')[1]
    if email_domain in self.bad_domains:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Registration using free email addresses is prohibited. Please supply a different email address."))
```

Similarly I want to run custom validation on different fields other than email address. How can I perform this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some adapters on the allauth configuration. For example this one:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER (="allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter")
    Specifies the adapter class to use, allowing you to alter certain default behaviour.
```

You can specify a new adapter by overriding the default one. Just override the *clean_email* method.

```
class MyCoolAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def clean_email(self, email):
        """
        Validates an email value. You can hook into this if you want to
        (dynamically) restrict what email addresses can be chosen.
        """
        *** here goes your code ***
        return email
```

Then modify the ACCOUNT_ADAPTER on the settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = '**app**.MyCoolAdapter'
```

Check the default behavior on:
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/adapter.py

Comment: To reject an email address, raise a `django.forms.ValidationError` exception.

Comment: how do do this on another form field ?

Comment: What should be returned if the email is declined?