# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing form class pages.custom_sign_up_form: "cannot import name 'BaseSignupForm'"

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to extend SignupForm of django allauth for customizing my signup form. The need is because i want to check if submitted email is accepted for signup or not and it is done by checking if the invite from that email is accepted or not by admin.

I have not define my form in forms.py instead i have used another name 'custom_sign_up_form.py'. Below is my full code with import.

**settings.py**

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'pages.custom_sign_up_form.CustomSignupForm'
```

**custom_sign_up_form.py**

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter, get_adapter
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from allauth.account import app_settings
# from django import forms

from invitation.models import Invitation

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    errors = {
        'not_invited': "Sorry! You are not yet invited.",
    }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).clean()
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if email and app_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            email = self.validate_unique_email(email)
        try:
            Invitation.objects.get(email=email, request_approved=True)
        except Invitation.DoesNotExist:
            # raise forms.ValidationError(errors['Sorry! you are not yet invited'])
            self.add_error('email','Sorry! You are not yet invited')
        return email
```

Comment: is this the same qustion? https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/572

Comment: There he says to use forms.Form instead of extending SignupForm. So i should now extend forms.Form class. However i am confused where should i write my validation logic. on Signup or clean function?

Comment: I got an answer to your question as I understood how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS** is **the parent class** of SignupForm (BaseSignupForm)...

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py#L197

If you want to change the Form validation logic, you need to use **ACCOUNT_ADAPTER**.

```
# project/settings.py:
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'project.users.adapter.MyAccountAdapter'

# project/users/adapter.py:
from django.conf import settings
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def clean_email(self, email):
        """
        Validates an email value. You can hook into this if you want to
        (dynamically) restrict what email addresses can be chosen.
        """
        try:
            Invitation.objects.get(email=email, request_approved=True)
        except Invitation.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry! you are not yet invited')
        return email
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23328414/7724457