# How does one redirect on an error in allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm currently am writing a site where the users fill out a form with some information to signup, and the server verifies the correctness of that information on its end before allowing a successful signup. If the information is invalid, I want the user to be redirected to a page that tells them what went wrong. I currently have the form/user adapter working and am now adding in the verification for social signup (manual signup is currently working fine, although the code is ugly).

Is there a way to add in a redirection in the form/adapter for social signup? If not, how do I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to handle this with redirection to a separate page, but rather with form validators.

By writing a custom adapter you should be able to override the default "clean" methods to display any error messages you want when the information is invalid.  In your adapter, simply raise a [django.forms.ValidationError on bad input](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/) and pass the error message back to the template that way.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304588/custom-form-validation-in-django-allauth) for more information on writing the custom form validator.